# Create a new object in Javascript with new reference -dont copy or clone-

Tags: javascript, json, clone

I have tried with: Object.assign(), Object.create(),Object.hasOwnProperty() but this create an empty object inside of my object, and copy the same reference.
Actually, I am doing this, but it is not correct in terms of resources, memory,...

Any suggestion or alternative?

```
listTypes = GWStypes["name_attr_JSON"];
var objectClone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(listTypes));                        
MMSignalsObject[signalName] = objectClone;
```

Comment: Slow down there. What are you trying to do? What *is* this doing instead?

Comment: The title makes it sound like you just want `var myObject = {};` but then the body of your question completely loses me. I have no idea what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I would like to create/copy/clone a new object in Javascript from other created object, but his reference cant be the same. When I inspect the object in the stack debugger, I check the two objects are pointed in the same address memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following ES6 syntax:

```
var objectClone = Object.assign({}, ...listTypes);
```

This assigns to a new object (with a new reference!) using all the key-values from listTypes using the 'spread' operator.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. This actually create a new object as empty by default and it is assigned with the copy of the value

```
var MMSignalsObject = {};
MMSignalsObject.signalName = objectClone;
```